# EF 4 Dynamic Where Clause not working

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am trying to create a query with a Dynamic where clause in EF version 4 and the only where clause that is being generated is the "c.clientid == Clientid" from the initial statement. looking at the SQL Profiler the `result.where` statements are not being appended to the result variable. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
var result = (from c in cxt.Customer
                              where c.clientid == Clientid
                              select c);

                string employeenumber = formdata["employeenumber"].ToString();
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(employeenumber))
                {
                    result.Where(t => t.EmployeeNumber.ToLower() == employeenumber);
                }

                string FirstName = formdata["FirstName"].ToString();
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FirstName))
                {
                    result.Where(t => t.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(FirstName));
                }

               return result.ToList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't assign the result of `result.Where(...)` to your result variable.

In your if statements insert: `result = result.Where(...);`

Comment: I just came here with the same mistake. I wasn't aware that result.Where would return something, I thought it was a function. Adding result = result.where did fix it for me. Thank you.